# Can I use a Dual Rank Memory with my Single Rank Memory?

Tags: memory, performance, compatibility, asus-laptop, ddr

I have a laptop with SAMSUNG 8GB DDR4 2400MHz single Ranked RAM and I buy another SAMSUNG 16GB DDR4 2400MHz dual ranked RAM

I want to know if they will work fine or I will have any compatibility problem!

My laptop : ASUS Vivobook 15 X510UF with intel i7-8550u CPU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an answer to my question, I installed a new 16GB Dual Rank RAM with my 8GB Single Rank RAM and it work fine for me.

I test it and there is no compability problem.

My BIOS set both of them to dual rank as you see with cpu-z [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0n9z.png)

Answer (score 1):

Not recommended. Don't mix memory types. Performance will suffer, blue screens and irregular behavior, too.

Comment: have you tried this and suffer from this problems ?

Comment: Yes, on hundreds of laptops I rebuilt and repaired at https://freegeek.org

Comment: i search a lot and i found a lot of people that they say there is no problem with using single rank with dual

Answer (score 1):

It might work but at best it will give you lopsided, reduced performance. Dual rank modules behave similarly to two single rank modules in different sockets on the same channel. It is also a virtual certainty that some, if not all, timings will be different. If you are lucky, the BIOS will set the slowest of the two for each of the timings programmed into the modules and it might work.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can use ram  Dual rank with Single rank on you Laptop and PC but you RAM performance will has reduce performance Read Write Copy so lowly but not have any problems on you laptop unlees like i saidy (Sorry my English  not good)